# Is there way to unit test validation annotations without having to use a dependency from glassfish?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, websphere

For this MovieForm class I have created:

```
public class MovieForm {

  private String movieName;

  @Min(1)
  @Max(31)
  @NotNull
  private Integer maxNumberOfTickets;
}
```

I have created this unit test that tests my validation annotations of my form.

```
public class MovieFormTest {

private static ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;
private static Validator validator;

@BeforeClass
public static void createValidator() {
    validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
}

@AfterClass
public static void close() {
    validatorFactory.close();
}

@Test
public void form_test() {
    MovieForm form = new MovieForm();
    form.setMaxNumberOfTickets(null);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MovieForm>> violations = validator.validate(form);
    Assert.assertFalse(violations.isEmpty());
    ConstraintViolation<MovieForm> violation = violations.iterator().next();
    Assert.assertEquals("may not be null", violation.getMessage());

    form.setMaxNumberOfTickets(32);
    violations = validator.validate(form);
    Assert.assertFalse(violations.isEmpty());
    violation = violations.iterator().next();
    Assert.assertEquals("must be less than or equal to 31", violation.getMessage());

    form.setMaxNumberOfTickets(0);
    violations = validator.validate(form);
    Assert.assertFalse(violations.isEmpty());
    violation = violations.iterator().next();
    Assert.assertEquals("must be greater than or equal to 1", violation.getMessage());

    form.setMaxNumberOfTickets(15);
    violations = validator.validate(form);
    Assert.assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
}
```

But this test only works when I add this glassfish dependency in my pom

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
 </dependency>
```

Or else I get a **HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'.** error. However my coworker doesn't want me to use this dependency because we are using WebSphere, so my question is this: is there way to get this unit test to work without having to use that dependency?

Comment: You could add `<scope>test</scope>` to your dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Create maven profile having this dependency (as Alayor suggested in his comment) in test scope

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>validation-test</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies> 
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Run tests with this profile enabled.
If need to test with any other implementation just a new profile

Of course in build phase you need to add either some corresponding validation-api or use the WebSphere implementation as dependency and with `<scope>provided</scope>` if deployed to container having impl already.